# Optimal Strategy for Loading and Serving Large ML Models for Efficient Recommendations in Production

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, flask, flask-restful

I have a Flask app with a large 7GB machine learning model. Model has to be loaded immediately after deployment. Loading the model is resource-intensive, particularly when the app handles multiple simultaneous requests. Should I load the model once and reuse it for each request, rather than loading it for every incoming request? I'm new to Flask. Also, I'm unsure why my app is struggling to handle the load.

Approach - 1

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the model only once and store it in the app context
model_dict = None

@app.before_first_request
def load_model():
    global model_dict
    model_dict = model_fn(MODEL_DIR)

@app.route("/recommendations", methods=["GET"])
def recommendations():
    response = dict(data=[], has_next=False)
    user_id = request.args["user_id"]
    data = serve_recommendations(request.args, model_dict)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=FLASK_APP_HOST, port=FLASK_APP_PORT)
```

Approach - 2

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

model_dict = download_model(MODEL_DIR)

@app.route("/recommendations", methods=["GET"])
def recommendations():
    response = dict(data=[], has_next=False)
    user_id = request.args["user_id"]
    data = serve_recommendations(request.args, model_dict)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=FLASK_APP_HOST, port=FLASK_APP_PORT)
```